# How make rewrite rules relative to .htaccess file

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Current I have an .htaccess file like this.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(always|rewrite|these|dirs)/ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php [L,QSA]
```

It works create when the site files are in the document_root of the webserver (ie. `domain.com/abc.php` -> `<DOCUMENT_ROOT>/abc.php`). But in our current setup (which isn't changeable), this isn't ensured. We can sometimes have arbitrary folder in between the document root and folder of the .htaccess file (ie. `domain.com/something/abc.php` -> `<DOCUMENT_ROOT>/something/abc.php`). The only problem with is that is the second `RewriteCond` no longer works. Is there anyway to dynamically check if the accessed path by a path relative to `.htaccess` file.

For Example:

If I have a site where `domain.com/prefix/` is the directory of the `.htaccess` file.

```
NOT FORCED TO REWRITE -> domain.com/prefix/index.php
FORCED TO REWRITE -> domain.com/prefix/rewrite/index.php
```

If I have a site where `domain.com/` is the directory of the `.htaccess` file.

```
NOT FORCED TO REWRITE -> domain.com/index.php
FORCED TO REWRITE -> domain.com/rewrite/index.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a solution but it's not simple.

Use `RewriteMap`.

Here's how I would do:

Create a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) file. See [here for more information](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap). This is a very simple text file with: first, the wrong URL *without the '/'*, then **one space** (at least) and then the right url, like this:

```
ok​ /folder1/
ok /folder2/
ok /folder3/
```

Then the code:

```
RewriteMap myfoldermap \
  dbm:/web/htdocs/yourwebsite.com/rewriterules/myfoldermap.map

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(.*)
# Now in '%1' there's the name of the folder
# Don't touch the URL but...
# ...check if it exists in the map file
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=FOLDERMAP:${myfoldermap:%1|notfound}]

# if the environment is neither empty or not found...
RewriteCond %{E:FOLDERMAP} !^(notfound|)$
# this means we found something...
# => apply the RewriteRule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php [L,QSA]
```

If it doesn't work: read my usual "two hints", and add the rewrite log in your question.

### Two hints:

If you're not in a hosted environment (= if it's your own server and you can modify the virtual hosts, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Answer (score 1):

Does *Forced to rewrite* means that the rewrite rule should work even if requested file or directory exists?

If yes, just try to avoid creating the file / directory.

Or seperate it to two rules:

> RewriteRule ^/(always|rewrite|these|dirs)/ router.php [L]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand you correctly (particularly I don't know what you mean with *forced to rewrite*), [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) is for you.

BTW: [don't use stuff like *domain.com*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com) :-)